# Did only 9700 women reply to messages on AshleyMadison.com?

Tags: economics

From [Gizmodo.com](http://gizmodo.com/almost-none-of-the-women-in-the-ashley-madison-database-1725558944):

> Yet another field, reply_mail_last_time, showed a similar disparity. This field contained the time when a member had last replied to a message from another person on Ashley Madison. 5.9 million men had done it, and only 9700 women had.

This implies an upper bound on the number of affairs between men and women facilitated on AshleyMadison.com is 9700. Even by the standards of dating sites, this seems impossibly low, a "success" rate of 1 in 500 just for a reply.

Comment: This seems to be very closely related to [Are 95% of Ashley Madison dating site's accounts male?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/are-95-of-ashley-madison-dating-sites-accounts-male). Can we merge them?

Comment: @Oddthinking what would an answer to this question look like? Someone else could verify that "reply_mail_last_time" was only set for 9700 women, but that's not really any better than what we've got already with the Gizmodo article. I'd suggest that we just close this question with a link to the other one. Something like - "This question seems unanswerable. Here's a related answerable question - link"