# Do Lovoo and Ashley Madison use chatbots ("fembots") to flirt with male customers?

Tags: sexuality, internet

Sites such as [Ashley Madison](http://gizmodo.com/how-ashley-madison-hid-its-fembot-con-from-users-and-in-1728410265) and German dating site [Lovoo](http://gizmodo.com/popular-german-dating-site-lovoo-may-use-fembots-to-lur-1733923755) have been accused of creating and programming fake female profiles to flirt with male customers. Although creating a profile for membership is free on those sites, it will cost money to reveal the details of the user who has given a free member a good rating.

So is "fembot" programming commonly used by these sites as claimed by Gizmodo?

Comment: I know that there is a series of sites that admit to doing this. I can't access them at work (firewall for adult sites). But they have members marked as "Fantasy Cuties" by a yellow star with FC in it. Of course, you have to click on it and scroll through a bunch of legalese to uncover this. I think the sites are AffairAlert, Blackcrush, MILFHunter, or whatever.

Comment: @user19555 - FWIW, the "sites" aren't always a distinct entity. One of the business tactics some companies engage in is to have a multitude of differently skinned and differently named sites all of which are really the same network. This applies even to "legit" personals sites like Plenty of Fish, i think

Comment: Related (not sure if duplicate?): http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28820/1044

Comment: @user5341-The question and answer highlighted by you talks about the Ashley Madison user population which is 85.96% Male profiles and 15.04% female profiles. However it does not further categorize this 15.04% into a proportion of fembots a.k.a chatbots as alleged in this claim apart from the discussed fake, unused, unconfirmed and unpaid profiles.

Comment: @pericles316: wow, that's a whopping 101% ;)

Comment: I am certain Lovoo does that. Just create a new profile, use the most hideous image you have available and a total stupid profile text, interact a bit with the app. You will get a message from at least one "female". I am certain, no real women would write such a profile. Source: tried myself